# AWS Question on EC2 was shutdown for 3:23 hrs, how much will you charge for it 0, 3, 4, 3:23 or 3.24 hrs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

An EC2 was provisioned and then the EC2 was shut down after running for 3:23 hrs, how much will you charge for it 0, 3, 4, 3:23 or 3.24 hrs?

Comment: Which operating system was it using?

Comment: Is this an actual business question, or is it just a poorly-worded sample exam question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an on-demand instance: "Effective October 2nd, usage of Linux instances that are launched in On-Demand, Reserved, and Spot form will be billed in one-second increments." (this was from October 2017)

(ref: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/)

So you would be charged: (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 3 (for the 3 hours)) + (60 seconds * 23 minutes (for the 23 minutes)) = 10800 + 1380 = 12180 seconds of usage.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances are charged for per-second usage. The charges depend on few things such as

- Time in seconds that ec2-instance is running.
- EC2 charges are dependent on the region your instance is running
- OS if it is licensed
- AMI cost, if it is not free
- EBS volume charges depends on the size
- Elastic IP addresses charges if one is attached
- Data transfer charges

Answer (score 0):

AWS pricing model differs based on the flavour of your EC2 instance. You need to calculate based on it. You can easily check with AWS pricing calculator or you can manually calculate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the charges for the timerange ( start - stop) in your cost analyzer report if not generated you can request one from the AWS support team.
Hope this helps.